# How to allow non-UTF8 for appengine datastore keys

Tags: google-app-engine

Anybody knows how to allow non-utf8 for appengine datastore keys?
I am using appengine for go.

Below is the error i get if i put non-utf8.

```
API error 1 (datastore_v3: BAD_REQUEST): key path element name is not valid UTF-8
```

> **project member said it is a design decision:**
>   https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12896

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you convert your String into UTF-8?

Comment: i am trying to create a custom store, using blevesearch. bleves uses non-utf8 in key names.

Comment: It does not mean you cannot convert it to UTF-8 when using it, or strip/replace non-compliant characters. You cannot change the way Cloud Datastore works, so you need to solve it on your end.

Comment: i would verify how blevesearch works internally first. changing its format should be my last option.

Comment: but, i would expect non-utf8 to work with datastore key names.

Comment: You should check which characters cause the exception.

Comment: yes, i know which one. but, it was purposely added there; it's how bleve format it's keys.
--> project member answered the feature request, and this post is updated
--> thank you very much for your concern.